# CodeIgniter Json Ajax Database insertion is not working

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have tried to solve this issue, here i am inserting dynamic inputbox box values into database including their title. But not working...

Inputbox dynamic generation: (This works well)

```
 $('#myTable tbody').append("<tr><td>"+rno+"</td><td>"
            +item.stdname+"</td><td><input type='text' name='stdmark[]' class='mark' title='"+item.stdid+"' style='padding: 0px; width: 50px;'/></td></tr>");
```

Ajax to Send these values into controller:

```
$('#marklist').submit(function(e){
  //var mark = 10;

    jsonObj = [];
    $("input[class=mark]").each(function() {

        var id = $(this).attr("title");
        var subjectmark = $(this).val();

        item = {}
        item ["stdid"] = id;
        item ["mark"] = subjectmark;

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>office/addmark",
      data: {senddata :JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
      dataType: "json",
      processData:false,
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      async:false,
      success:
           function(retrived_data){


                }
       });
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Controller:

```
public function addmark()
{
 $marks = json_decode($this->input->post('senddata'), true);
  $this->load->Model('wtcmodel');
foreach($marks as $row)
      {
        $data = array(
          'stdid' =>  $row->stdid,
          'mark' => $row->mark
        );
      $this->wtcmodel->adddata($data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function adddata($data)
         {
              $this->load->database();
              $this->db->insert('table_info',$data);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can post input data using this method.

```
 var stdid = $('input[name="stdmark[]"]').map(function(){ 
                    return $(this).attr('title');
                }).get();

 var marks = $('input[name="stdmark[]"]').map(function(){ 
                    return this.value;
                }).get();

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'users.php',
    data: {
        'stdid[]': stdid,
        'marks[]':marks
    },
    success: function() {
    }
});
```

You can access `stdid[]` and `marks[]` variable as array directly in controller.

Controller

```
public function addmark()
{
 $stdid = $this->input->post('stdid');
 $marks = $this->input->post('marks');
 $this->load->Model('wtcmodel');
 foreach($stdid as $key => $row)
      {
        $data = array(
          'stdid' => $stdid,
          'mark' => $marks[$key]
        );
      $this->wtcmodel->adddata($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to post input values and their title to the controller

Comment: but.. not working.. there was a hidden input value at first, i removed it. Actually i want to insert mark of a student with id. I made the id as the input box 'title'. then i used json

Comment: Then u have to iterate stdmark[] twice .. I had update answer

Comment: Even this dummy values are not working.
$stdid = $this->input->post('stdid');
     $marks = $this->input->post('mark');
     $this->load->Model('wtcmodel');
    foreach($stdid as $key => $row)
          {
            $data = array(
              'stdid' => 10,
              'mark' => 25
            );
          $this->wtcmodel->addmarks($data);
        }

Comment: Then there is some problem with db configuration. Please check there also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166151/discussion-between-infolet-org-and-mayank-majithya).

Answer (score 0):

why did't use Jquery `serialize` function : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
 $('#marklist').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //var mark = 10;

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>office/addmark",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          dataType: "json",
          processData:false,
          contentType:false,
          cache:false,
          async:false,
          success:
          function(retrived_data){}
       });


  });
```

or you can use `param` : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: I want to post input values and their title to the controlle